# Speech recognition for Korean language on Microsoft Windows

Tags: windows-7, speech-recognition

I am looking for a speech recognition program for the Korean language on Microsoft Windows 7.

---

As far as I know:

- Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12 and 13 does not support Korean
- Microsoft speech recognition does not support Korean. ([Source](http://www.sevenforums.com/windows-updates-activation/320479-help-cant-use-korean-speech-recognize-windows-7-a.html): "*Speech Recognition is available only in English, French, Spanish, German, Japanese, Simplified Chinese, and Traditional Chinese.*".  [Microsoft Speech Platform SDK 11 does have Korean though](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh378476(v=office.14).aspx))

I haven't checked which languages and OSes the following programs support, but they had an unsatisfyingly speech recognition accuracy on the English language last time I tried:

- [CMU Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/)
- [CVoiceControl](http://www.kiecza.net/daniel/linux/)
- [Ears](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/comp.speech/Section6/Recognition/ears.html)
- [Julius](http://julius.osdn.jp/)
- [Kaldi](http://kaldi.sourceforge.net/)
- [NICO ANN Toolkit](http://nico.nikkostrom.com/)
- [OpenMindSpeech](http://freespeech.sourceforge.net/)
- [RWTH ASR](http://www-i6.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/rwth-asr/)
- [shout](http://shout-toolkit.sourceforge.net/)
- [Simon Listens](http://simon-listens.org/index.php?id=122)
- [ViaVoice / Xvoice](http://xvoice.sourceforge.net/)

They are mostly designed to work for Linux, and not so plug-and-play.

I can use Google speech recognition in Google document but I'd prefer something that works OS-wide, i.e., not restricted to the browser.